# Strange parse error in demo.xml

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I am following the official odoo-9's tutorial for building modules. Following the the  [Data Files](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/howtos/backend.html#data-files) section, I placed the following piece of code into `openacademy/demo/demo.xml`:

```
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record model="openacademy.course" id="course0">
            <field name="name">Course 0</field>
            <field name="description">Course 0's description

Can have multiple lines
            </field>
        </record>
        <record model="openacademy.course" id="course1">
            <field name="name">Course 1</field>
            <!-- no description for this one -->
        </record>
        <record model="openacademy.course" id="course2">
            <field name="name">Course 2</field>
            <field name="description">Course 2's description</field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

But, when I try to install my module, I face the following error:

```
...
File "D:\odoo-dev\odoo-9.0\openerp\tools\convert.py", line 630, in _tag_record
    model = self.pool[rec_model]
  File "D:\odoo-dev\odoo-9.0\openerp\modules\registry.py", line 84, in __getitem__
    return self.models[model_name]
ParseError: "openacademy.course" while parsing file:///D:/odoo-dev/odoo-addons/openacademy/demo/demo.xml:3, near
<record model="openacademy.course" id="course0">
            <field name="name">Course 0</field>
            <field name="description">Course 0's description

Can have multiple lines
            </field>
        </record>
```

**Update**
I removed the apostrophes completely from the xml file. But I still get the same error.

```
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record model="openacademy.course" id="course0">
            <field name="name">Course 0</field>
            <field name="description">Course 0 description Can have multiple lines
            </field>
        </record>
        <record model="openacademy.course" id="course1">
            <field name="name">Course 1</field>
            <field name="description">Description 2</field>
        </record>
        <record model="openacademy.course" id="course2">
            <field name="name">Course 2</field>
            <field name="description">Course 2 description</field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

The error:

```
...
ParseError: "openacademy.course" while parsing file:///D:/odoo-dev/odoo-addons/openacademy/demo/demo.xml:3, near
<record model="openacademy.course" id="course0">
            <field name="name">Course 0</field>
            <field name="description">Course 0 description Can have multiple lines
            </field>
        </record>
```

Comment: Hello , Can you provide .py file and openerp file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I have used the scaffolding tool to generate the structure of my module as described in the official documentation. The scaffolding tool generates the following structure:

```
odoo-addons/
|_ openacademy/
  |_controllers/
  |_demo/
  |_models/
  | |_ models.py
  |
  |_security/
  |_views/
  |_ __init__.py
  |_ __openerp__.py
```

And in the `__init__.py` I have placed the following as described in the documentation:

```
from . import controllers
from . import models
```

And in the `demo.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="course_list_action">
            <field name="name">Courses</field>
            <field name="res_model">openacademy.course</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            <field name="help" type="html">
                <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Create the first course</p>
            </field>
        </record>
        <menuitem id="main_openacademy_menu" name="Open Academy"/>
        <menuitem id="openacademy_menu" name="Open Academy" parent="main_openacademy_menu"/>
        <menuitem id="courses_menu" name="Courses" parent="openacademy_menu"
                  action="course_list_action"/>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

As you can see the `res_model` field is set to `openacademy.course` which python cannot find because it is not loaded in the `__init__.py` file. Changing it to the following solved my problem:

```
from controllers import controllers
from models import models
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few characters you can't use in XML literals. The `'` apostrophe is one of them.

Instead use an escape value, such as `&apos;` or `&#39;`.

You can find more about this on the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As in my updated question, I completely removed the apostrophes, But I still get the same error.